# MySQL Ordering: Put at bottom if field = X or A, otherwise order by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a status field. If the status is 'done' or 'removed', I want to show them at the bottom of the list, always.

Above that, I don't care about the status but want to order by date created.

I can imagine doing it with s sub select but how could I do that with one query?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY status IN ('done','removed'), dateCreated
```